# How to call a dropbox api using curl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dropbox

I have a dropbox controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("dropbox")
public class DropboxController {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropboxController.class);

@Autowired
DropboxService dropboxService;

@Autowired
DbxClientV2 dropboxClient;

@GetMapping("/list")
public List<Map<String, Object>> index(@RequestParam(value = "target", required = false, defaultValue = "") String target) throws Exception {
    return dropboxService.getFileList(target);
}
```

A Springboot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "aic.filestorage2.controller",
        "aic.filestorage2.service"
})

@Import({WebConfig.class})
public class DropboxExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DropboxExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
@Bean("dropboxClient")
public DbxClientV2 dropboxClient() throws DbxException {
    String ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    return client;


}
}
```

How do I then need to call it when using curl?
When I try it like `dropbox/list` or `localhost:8080/dropbox/list` it says "could not resolve host" or for the second one "status:404"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the RequestMapping defined differently than I use them.

Try this:

```
@RestController
public class DropboxController {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropboxController.class);

@Autowired
DropboxService dropboxService;

@Autowired
DbxClientV2 dropboxClient;

@RequestMapping(value="/dropbox/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Map<String, Object>> index(@RequestParam(value = "target", required = false, defaultValue = "") String target) throws Exception {
    return dropboxService.getFileList(target);
}
```

Your curl command would look like this:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/dropbox/list?target=myfile
```